# Barcode scanner crashing with memory leak in android

Tags: android

Below is the activity which allows user to scan QR code, ask is Barcodedetector release method is called only on couple of device & not able to detect when is ideally this method called & whats the reason behind it. Any clue will be highly appriciated.

```
public class ScannedBarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    TextView txtBarcodeValue;
    private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
     String intentData = "";
    boolean isEmail = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanned_barcode);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    }

    private void initialiseDetectorsAndSources() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode scanner started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                .build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true) //you should add this feature
                .build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this, new
                                String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });


        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To prevent memory leaks barcode scanner has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    txtBarcodeValue.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                           Intent pushBack = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this,TypeALabelActivity.class);

                           String type = "";
                            JSONObject obj = null;
                            try {
                                obj = new JSONObject(intentData);
                                type = obj.getString("LType");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                           if(type.equals("B")){
                               pushBack = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this,TypeBLabelActivity.class);
                           }else if(type.equals("C")){
                               pushBack = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this,TypeCLabelActivity.class);
                           }else if(type.equals("D")){
                               pushBack = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this,TypeDLabelActivity.class);
                           }else if(type.equals("E")){
                               pushBack = new Intent(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this,TypeELabelActivity.class);
                           }
                            System.out.println("intentData" + intentData);
                           pushBack.putExtra("QR",intentData);
                           startActivity(pushBack);
                           finish();

//                            if (barcodes.valueAt(0).email != null) {
//                                txtBarcodeValue.removeCallbacks(null);
//                                intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).email.address;
//                                txtBarcodeValue.setText(intentData);
//                                isEmail = true;
//                             } else {
//                                isEmail = false;
//
//                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraSource.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initialiseDetectorsAndSources();
    }
}
```

Crashing after scanning QR in below method:-

```
@Override
                public void release() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To prevent memory leaks barcode scanner has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Below is only device where its crashing
[image]

**Note:-** This device is been testing on end user side & dont have control/access to logs. This is the only device where its crashing

Comment: You have to show us the logcat error. It will tell you why it's crashing. In Android Studio there is a tab called "Logcat".

Comment: @zomega - Yes I am aware of logcat, This device is been testing on end user side & dont have control/access to logs. This is the only device where its crashing